# I created tag and it is not showing up on the webpage

Tags: javascript, html

It should happen like this when I am pressing 'ADD TODO' if it's empty it should create a p tag after input 'enter your TODO', now  although the js is creating the element but it isn't showing up on the webpage

HTML:

```
<h1 class="head">MY LIST</h1>
<input type="text" id='input'>
<button id='add' type="buttton">ADD TODO</button><br>
```

remove TODO
remove everything

JS:

```
function addItem() {

    var input =document.getElementById('input');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(input.value)

    if(input.value === '') {
  
        var par=document.createElement('p')
        par.textContent='enter TODO please';
        par.setAttribute('id','new')
   
        // I have only put here the if case
        document.querySelector('input').appendChild(par); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to set the click event for your button. Right now, the button is just calling the default action instead of your function. To do this, the tags for the button need to be

```
<button id='add' type="button" onclick="addItem()">ADD TODO</button><br>
```

Right now, your button is trying to add a paragraph as a child to the input and not after. To add the paragraph after you need to change the last line of your JS to

```
document.querySelector('input').after(par);
```